# How to refresh the current page after current time is out

Tags: timer, set, settimeout

Hi i want to refresh the page after any of the ID time expire

`<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("divID();",1000); 
    function divID(){
      $('#btime').load(location.href + ' #bitime');
      $('#rtime').load(location.href + ' #retime');
      $('#stime').load(location.href + ' #shtime');
    }
  </script>`

```
<div id="btime"><div id="bitime"></div></div>
<div id="rtime"><div id="retime"></div></div>
<div id="stime"><div id="shtime"></div></div>
```

After any of the div ID when time expire i want to refresh the page once, please how can i do that continuing using my actual script ?

Answer (score 0):

Once any of your ID time expire you can use [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) to reload the page.

```
setInterval(function() {
  divID();
  checkIdExpired();
}, 1000); 

function checkIdExpired() {
 $('#btime, #rtime, #stime').each(function(el){
    // Here your condition
    if ($(el).html() === 'something') {
      // Reload
      location.reload(); 
    }
  });
};

function divID() {
  $('#btime').load(location.href + ' #bitime');
  $('#rtime').load(location.href + ' #retime');
  $('#stime').load(location.href + ' #shtime');
}
```

Comment: My actual interval function refresh the countdown of the divs every second and i want to reload the whole current page once when one of the countdown timers of any of the 3 divs expire, i dont want to reload the whole page every second.

Comment: How are your getting when any of your 3 divs timers expire??

Comment: `<div id="stime">
<div id="shtime">
<div class="timer" data-time="{$buildInfo.fleet['timeleft']}">
{$buildInfo.fleet['starttime']}
</div>
</div>
</div>` i use smarty inside my webpage